# Replace the "wp-admin" in the URL with "xyz-admin" in WordPress dashboard

Tags: login, urls, wp-login-form, site-url

I want to replace the "wp-admin" in my URL with "xyz-admin" all across my dashboard after a user logs in. I know that there are some plugins that could help, but those plugins only change the URL for the login screen but when a user logs in the "wp-admin" appears. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: this might not be possible and will be quite difficult, hence the lack of plugins. A lot of plugins and themes hardcode `wp-admin` and no constants/filters are provided for changing the admin location in the same way that login/wp-content/etc have. What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? Note that changing the login URLs etc don't improve your sites security even though it sounds like it would, and will not stop spam requests to those URLs

Comment: Sir, I would like to make my website a white label to ensure that users with limited dashboard access cannot identify that it is developed using WordPress. I appreciate your assistance in this matter